# Why failing to get CRAN key for R backports?

Tags: debian, software-installation, key-authentication, r

I do and get

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/10260634/54964
root@masi:/home/masi/Documents# gpg --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-key  06F90DE5381BA480
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 381BA480 from hkp server subkeys.pgp.net
?: subkeys.pgp.net: Network is unreachable
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Network is unreachable
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

I am trying to change to R backports because I need R 3.3.2, so I did already the addition of the following line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://cran.wu.ac.at/bin/linux/debian jessie-cran3/
```

### Iterating rcs' proposal

```
root@masi:/home/masi/Documents# gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 06F90DE5381BA480
gpg: requesting key 381BA480 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 381BA480: public key "Johannes Ranke (CRAN Debian archive) <jranke@uni-bremen.de>" imported
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

root@masi:/home/masi/Documents# apt-get update
...
Fetched 116 kB in 3s (32.1 kB/s)         
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://cran.wu.ac.at jessie-cran3/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 06F90DE5381BA480
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Try `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 06F90DE5381BA480`

Comment: Worked, but I get now `W: GPG error: http://cran.wu.ac.at jessie-cran3/ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 06F90DE5381BA480` from `apt-get update`. - - Do you understand why? Do you understand why `apt-get` cannot use the key?

Comment: Does this work? `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 6212B7B7931C4BB16280BA1306F90DE5381BA480`

Comment: @rcs Yes, it works. Confirmed by `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. Please, make it an answer and explain why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [installation instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian) for Debian packages on CRAN, section [Secure apt](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#secure-apt):

> The Debian backports archives on CRAN are signed with the key of
>   Johannes Ranke (CRAN Debian archive) with key
>   fingerprint 6212 B7B7 931C 4BB1 6280  BA13 06F9 0DE5 381B A480. You
>   can fetch and import this with

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 6212B7B7931C4BB16280BA1306F90DE5381BA480
```