# secure apt R pgp key no_pubkeys found

Tags: linux, debian, apt, r, pgp

I already applied the solutions on these pages 
[Why failing to get CRAN key for R backports?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324543/why-failing-to-get-cran-key-for-r-backports/324547#324547?newreg=e9d26f58a62541fea4570305d4e5b8ff)

and

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#secure-apt

for installing R on Debian Linux Jessie

But every time I do `apt-get update`, it display NOPUBKEYS and key error. How to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the key manually following the alternative method posted on the [official website](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/#secure-apt):

> If this doesn’t work, it might be due to a firewall blocking port 11371. Alternatively, you can search for 0x381BA480 at http://keys.gnupg.net (check “Show PGP Fingerprints”), check the fingerprint and copy the key block into a plain text file, named, for instance, jranke_cran.asc wich you add to apt with apt-key add.

Past the string :`0x381BA480` [here](http://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net/) then search for the key : [Result](http://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x06F90DE5381BA480)

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: SKS 1.1.5
Comment: Hostname: keys.nerds.lu
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=BRgm
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Copy it with your favorite text editor, save it as : `jranke_cran.asc`

open the terminal and run:

```
# apt-key add jranke_cran.asc
# apt-get update
```